# Find highlighted text, and modify it, VBA word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a large document that has been converted from a pdf and I am trying to do some cleanup on it. There are a few portions of text that have a text highlight, for example, if the bolded text had a highlight: "Lorem ipsum **dolor sit** amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu tempus mauris, sit amet **ultricies** massa. Phasellus **rhoncus magna ac pharetra** aliquam." I want to find every instance of a highlighted text, and essentially add a label to it and remove the highlight, like: "Lorem ipsum [label: dolor sit] amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu tempus mauris, sit amet [label: ultricies] massa. Phasellus [label: rhoncus magna ac pharetra] aliquam."

I'm using VBA and have tried a number of variations of find. I was first trying to iterate paragraph by paragraph, but that got tedious. My most recent iteration looks like this, and seems to affect the entire document and adds the specified text at the beginning of the doc rather than replacing the highlight that is supposedly found with `.Highlight = True`:

```
Set curDoc = Documents.Open(filePath, Visible:=True)
with curDoc.Range.Find
    .Highlight = True
        Do While .Execute
            curDoc.Range.Text = "[label: " + curDoc.Range.Text + "]"
            curDoc.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
            curDoc.Range.Font.Color = wdAuto
        Loop
End With
```

Comment: Note that there are times in a Word document that turning Bold off will actually turn it on, depending on underlying formatting. This is a toggle property in Word and two falses = a true.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing because you haven't constructed it correctly. When you use `.Find` with a `Range` object `Find` redefines it to the range of the match. However, because of the way you have constructed your `With` statement `curDoc.Range` always points to the entire document.

The code below should get you going in the right direction.

```
With curDoc.Range
   .Find.Highlight = True
   Do While .Find.Execute
      .HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
      .Text = "[label: " & .Text & "]"
      .Font.Color = wdAuto
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
   Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following method, if any bold text are found, then change the text as per you expected, please take note when you are looking other style of highlighted text, remember to turn it off like `font.bold = false`, else infinite loop will trigger:

```
Sub test()

Dim sentence As Range
Dim w As Range

For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    For Each w In sentence.Words
        If w.Font.Bold = True Then
            w.Text = "[Label: " + w.Text + "]"
            w.Font.Bold = False
            w.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
            w.Font.Color = wdAuto
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this not iterating over every single word in the document, then? What if my doc is huge? Is .Find not more efficient?

Comment: @pianoman102 - `.Find` is far more efficient and perfectly capable of finding bolded text.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt do you know how my problem could be solved then? I'm trying to find and modify highlighted text in word. The bold text was just as an example, but I'm really wanting to know about finding highlighted text.

Comment: You will up to your choice for the method to match a string, The function not only check word, but also other word like comma and so on, you can use debug.print then you will notice it.